# Laravel breadcrumbs bundle cannot find custom template

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, breadcrumbs

I am using https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs package.

Installed as it says in instructions, but i want to create a custom template for my breadcrumbs.

I have created app/breadcrumbs.php:

```
Breadcrumbs::register('home', function($breadcrumbs) {
    $breadcrumbs->push('Home', route('home'));
});

Breadcrumbs::register('about', function($breadcrumbs) {
    $breadcrumbs->parent('home');
    $breadcrumbs->push('About company', route('about'));
});
```

Then in config file of that package:

```
return array(
    'view' => 'laravel-breadcrumbs::_partials.breadcrumbs',
);
```

Then created that view in app/views/_partials/breadcrumbs.blade.php:

```
@if ($breadcrumbs)
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
        @foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb)
            @if (!$breadcrumb->last)
                <li><a href="{{{ $breadcrumb->url }}}">{{{ $breadcrumb->title }}}</a></li>
            @else
                <li class="active">{{{ $breadcrumb->title }}}</li>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Then i am printing that breadcrumb in my view:

```
{{ Breadcrumbs::render('about') }}
```

However, i am getting error:

```
View [_partials.breadcrumbs] not found.
```

How it cannot be found if i created it?!? spent 4 hours to figure out that thing. Please. help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

James helped me. I had to do:

```
return array(
    'view' => '_partials.breadcrumbs',
);
```